# How to gracefully shut down a spring batch slave

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

We are using spring batch Remote partitioning for implementing batch jobs. During the start of the batch window we start a predefined set of slave JVMs.

For each individual job, we start a master. Master creates the partition contexts and slaves are picking and processing them. Slaves are common for all the 
jobs in the batch window.

At the end of the batch window we want to gracefully shutdown the slaves. Is there any other way rather than killing the slave JVMs.

Comment: `Slaves are common for all the jobs in the batch window.` is that working fine? Just to make sure I understand the requirement, you want to stop salves at a specific time (the end of batch window) and not after each worker has finished processing a partition (so each worker might handle multiple partitions). Is that correct?

Comment: @Mahmoud That's correct.

Comment: What are you running this on?  Bare metal/VMs or a platform?  If you're on a platform like CloudFoundry or Kubernetes, this gets a LOT easier...

Comment: @Minella yes, We are running on JVM.

Comment: In my project on Linux, we are using kill -9 to terminate slaves